# Mean-Field approximation during paramagnetic phase

Tags: solid-state-physics

Currently I'm using Charles Kittel's "Introduction to Solid-State Physics", 8th edition, and I've come across a problem that is the mean-field approximation.

It states that $B_E=\mu_0 \lambda M$ and this "extra" magnetic field is a resultant from the fact that my magnetic moments are parallel to each other in the ferromagnetic state. This is not a real magnetic field because of the fact that the "real" solution would be quantum mechanical. Alright, I don't understand it, but perhaps I have enough of knowledge to move further.

In the next chapter he derives a formula for the volume susceptibility of the paramagnetic phase, whereas he still use the $B_E$ i.e the meanfield-approximation which assumes that I have magnetic moment parallell to each other. According to me, the paramagnetic phase is the disordered phase whereas the ferromagnetic phase is the ordered.

Therefore I would assume that $B_E$ is 0 for the paramagnetic phase, but this seems to be wrong according to Kittel, what have I missed?

Comment: It is non-zero if the external magnetic field is non-zero.

Comment: Okay, so the order is then $B_a$ $\to$ $M$ $\to$ $B_E$ ?